# Change MAC PERMANENTLY(for wlan0)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I need to change my MAC permanently for `wlan0` interface. **Macchanger** is a pretty good variant but after rebooting wifi card old MAC comes back. So, I don't like to use it.

I found one good solution for changing MAC permanently (but for `eth0`). Here it is: we open the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and add two lines:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp   
      hwaddress ether NEW_MAC
```

I've tried to do like this for `wlan0` interface but it doesn't work that way.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called "changeMAC.sh" in `/home/yourUser/` [Replacing yourUser accordingly]

In the file, paste this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
service network-manager stop
ifconfig wlan0 down
# Change to whatever MAC you want
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
ifconfig wlan0 up
service network-manager start
```

Then, in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), run

`sudo chmod +x /home/yourUser/changeMAC.sh` [Again, replacing yourUser accordingly]

Then run `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

At the bottom, add the line `sudo /home/yourUser/changeMAC.sh` [You know the drill, replace yourUser...]

Exit nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, pressing <kbd>y</kbd> to write changes to disk.

Finally, run `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: @ZhenyaAfnwefowa - Get root (`sudo su`) and then try running each of the commands in my answer one by one manually. You must be doing something wrong. **I have this working from a .sh file myself.**

Comment: I tried one more time - nothing. Then I decided to delete two line from script(what are about network-manager restarting). Reboot. While system was strarting up I saw smth like this:
due to rc.local
Old mAC:my_mac
New MAC :*********
But when I signed in the system and typed ifconfig wlan0, it shows me the OLD MAC , not the NEW one.

Do you know another way how to do it?

Comment: How could that work in rc.local if it simply doesn't work the way : sudo /home/USER/changeMAC.sh ?

Comment: I've rebooted my laptop so many times, check so many variants and still nothing.

Comment: @ZhenyaAfnwefowa *"How could that work in rc.local if it simply doesn't work the way : sudo /home/USER/changeMAC.sh"* That's why I'm asking muru if he has any insight.

Comment: Muru will not get any notifications from a post he has not interacted with. Catch him on chat or some other place and ask him rather. And I am going to tidy up some of the comments.

Comment: @ZhenyaAfnwefowa MAC address is hard coded into the hardware - you would have to manually run macchanger as suggested at boot via script to work.  Also, `/etc/rc.local` runs as root - no need for sudo there